# Problems with maven installation

Tags: java, maven-2, windows-7

Hi I'm trying to install [MAVEN](http://maven.apache.org), to my computer using [this](http://www.roseindia.net/maven2/installing_and_getting_hands_on_maven.shtml) tutorial, I've set my enviroment variable `MAVEN_HOME` to point to my maven directory, and I put value of `path_to_maven/bin` inside another enviroment variable named `Path` and I get this error message:

```
C:\>mvn -version
'mvn' is not recognized as an in
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried also to use `PATH` instead of `Path` but that doesn't solve it, what else can I do? I'm using windows 7..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to `path_to_maven/bin` and type `mvn -version`. If that works then it's a PATH problem.
In MS-DOS's prompt type `set PATH=path_to_maven/bin;%PATH%`

Comment: Running CMD as Administrator solves the PATH problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart your computer for the changes to PATH to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while configuring maven.

I've installed Maven 2 on my computer and I had problems when invoking mvn --version from cmd.

I've set the M2_HOME and M2_REPO environment variables and I have added to the **system variable** PATH the path_to_maven/bin.

In order to be able to invoke mvn from cmd I had to add still another **environment variable** named PATH with value path_to_maven/bin.

I hope this will help anyone caught in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone:

Try to add the entire directory path in the `PATH` variable instead of using the referrals like `%M2%`.

Answer (score -1):

Close the Command `Prompt` and then re-open it again.
Hit the command `mvn -version`. It should work if the `environment/system variables` are set properly.